# How to change the value of input text?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make the value of the first input text (number) disappear when I use the reset button as part of the following form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="number" value="<?php echo $result;?>">
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="reset">
    <p name="result">The result is: <?php echo $result; ?> </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Try echo all of the p tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset ONLY a single input tag in a formfield with just html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351557/how-to-reset-only-a-single-input-tag-in-a-formfield-with-just-html5)

Comment: input `type='reset'` reset the whole form, if you want to reset just one input, you have to define your own event handler. Have a look at my suggest dupplicate

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with JS:

**Define your elements**

```
let reset_btn = document.getElementById('btn-one');
let default_btn = document.getElementById('btn-two');
```

**When clicking on reset set value to null**

```
reset_btn.onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById('name-input').value = '';
}
```

**Set value back to default**

```
default_btn.onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById('name-input').value = '<?php echo $result;?>';
}
```

Remember to add id's to your btns.

Comment: i think because of the number on web address
like localhost/www/one.php?number=9
something like that

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="input" name="number" value="<?php echo $result;?>">
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="button" onclick="resetInput()" value="Reset">
    <p name="result">The result is: <?php echo $result; ?> </p>
</form>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function resetInput() {
    document.getElementById("input").value = "";
}
```

When clicking the button, the value of the first input with the id `input` will be set to an empty string.

Comment: i tried it didnt work

Comment: Did you set an ID to the input field? Did JavaScript throw any errors? If there were any errors can you post them? @PsymonTung

Comment: im sorry it do work, tq

Comment: No problem. It would be nice if you could mark the answer as correct :)